# Bridge pattern: how to define functions that call the implementation of the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am working on a polymer simulation code that employs the Bridge pattern to separate abstractions (the objects involved in the simulation) and their implementations (how they are represented e.g. one particle per monomer, continuous grid, etc.). A problem that I am facing is that I am struggling to define a class hierarchy of abstractions where lower abstractions can execute functions defined on other classes higher up in the hierarchy.

I would like to define a base abstraction `Monomer` that incorporates a number of methods that call the `MonomerImpl` implementation. Say, a method `applyDisplacement` to move the monomer in space. However, when I define a derived abstraction `MonomerTypeA` with several implementations `MonomerTypeAImplGrid`, `MonomerTypeAImplParticles`, etc., I would like to call `applyDisplacement`, defined at the top of the hierarchy class, but using the specific implementation of my monomer class.

This is an example of what I have tried:

```cpp
class Monomer
{
  public:
    ...
    void applyDisplacement(Vector displacement)
    {
       getImplementation()->applyDisplacement(displacement);
    }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<MonomerImpl> p_impl;
    virtual MonomerImpl* getImplementation();

};

class MonomerImpl
{
  public:
    ...
    void applyDisplacement(Vector displacement)
    {
       for (int i=0; i<positions.size(); i++)
       {
           positions[i] += displacement;
       }
    }

  private:
    std::vector<Vector> positions;

};
```

And:

```cpp
class MonomerTypeA : Monomer
{
  public:
    ...

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<MonomerTypeAImpl> p_impl;
    MonomerImpl* getImplementation()
    {
        return (MonomerImpl*) p_impl.get();
    }

};

class MonomerTypeAImpl : MonomerImpl
{
...
}
```

If I use a virtual function `getImplementation` function can only return a `MonomerImpl*` pointer, then I can't implement any additional functionality to the implementation. Alternatively, if I try to scrap inheritance and just define a bunch of different implementations, I will have **a lot** of code duplication.

Is there any solution that gets the best of both worlds?

Comment: As shown, you don't have any derived classes. Do you intend for `MonomerTypeA` to inherit from `Monomer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is going to be split between the code, some comments in the code, and text here.

First, the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// Create a pure virtual interface for your MonomerImpls
class MonomerImpl {
 public:
  virtual ~MonomerImpl() = default;  // Required in non-concrete classes
  void applyDisplacement(int displacement) {
    std::cout << "From pure virtual interface " << displacement << ":\n";
    applyDisplacement_Helper(displacement);
  }

  // Protected so inherited classes can access it freely
 protected:
  std::vector<int> positions{};

 private:
  // Helper
  virtual void applyDisplacement_Helper([[maybe_unused]] int displacement) = 0;
};

// Public inheritance is what you want a majority of the time
class MonomerTypeAImpl : public MonomerImpl {
 public:
  MonomerTypeAImpl() = default;

 private:
  void applyDisplacement_Helper([[maybe_unused]] int displacement) override {
    std::cout << "Specialization From Monomer A Impl\n";
  }
};

// Second MonomerImpl child to illlustrate
class MonomerTypeXImpl : public MonomerImpl {
 public:
  MonomerTypeXImpl() = default;

 private:
  void applyDisplacement_Helper([[maybe_unused]] int displacement) override {
    std::cout << "specialization From Monomer X Impl\nYowza\n";
  }
};

// If you'll have many Monomers, it's better for the base to be abstract
// In cases where this similar operation is being done, NVI (non-virtual
// interface) can be quite helpful.
//
// I just have a Monomer class, and you can feed different objects different
// MonomerImpls to get the desired behavior
class Monomer {
 public:
  Monomer(MonomerImpl* impl) : p_impl(impl) {}
  void applyDisplacement(int displacement) {
    p_impl->applyDisplacement(displacement);
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<MonomerImpl> p_impl;
  // I got rid of the get_impl() function, it added an extra step for no gain
};

int main() {
  MonomerImpl* monoImpl = new MonomerTypeAImpl();

  Monomer mono(monoImpl);
  mono.applyDisplacement(42);

  std::cout << "\n\n";

  Monomer xMono(new MonomerTypeXImpl());
  xMono.applyDisplacement(350);
}
```

Output:

```
From pure virtual interface:
From Monomer A Impl: 42


From pure virtual interface:
From Monomer X Impl: 350
Yowza
```

I had to remove your `Vector` class (wasn't provided), so I just changed it to an `int` so it would compile. The changes made were not major, as most of the pieces were already there. If you're going to have many different implementations, my recommendation is to create a pure virtual base class for the implementations. It standardizes interface and puts the code in the concrete (objects are declarable) classes where it belongs. Like I stated in a comment, if many of the derived classes would be doing the same thing, employing NVI or **N**on-**V**irtual **I**nterfaces can help with that. An example of NVI is in the class `MonomerImpl`.

(The idea behind NVI is that the base class callable (public) functions are not virtual. The base class, even if it's abstract, can do the things that are common to all children, and *then* call a protected/private virtual function that allows the children to do their specialized work, and only their specialized work. Order of when the virtual function gets called dependent on the common work, naturally)

With the code provided, I didn't feel that I gained anything by deriving from `Monomer` at all. You might have a reason to do so, if the different `MonomerImpl*`s aren't enough. Again, I'd recommend an abstract base class as a starting point.

If there are still questions, I am happy to try to answer them. As a reference to go with this answer, https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/bridge

Answer (score 0):

You have got the idea but your implementation is a little off shore.

> If I use a virtual function getImplementation function can only return a `MonomerImpl*` pointer, then I can't implement any additional functionality to the implementation

Correction: you will be able to implement additional functionality but only for `MonomerImpl` class. And also virtual fuctions work with inheritance so for that to work you must inherit from a base class or and abstruct class .ie an interface.

The issue is that you have not made the glue to connect the various implementations of `Monomer`. This connection between `Monomer` and it implementation classes can be achieve using inheritance or aggregation. But in this case aggregation won't be ideal becasue the is a **"is a"** relationship between `Monomer` and it implementations.

For example

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    class vector
    {
    };
    
    // design an abstract base class .ie interface with pure virtual functions
    // of all the functions that an implementation must define .
    // All these functions will be callable from our base class with polymorphism
    class monomer_intf
    {
      virtual auto
      do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void
          = 0;
    };
    
    // monomer is our concrete base class which will help use call our desired
    // implementations in the various derived class
    class monomer : public monomer_intf
    {
      // defined because pure virtual functions need to be defined in the derived
      // class else the derived class also becomes an abstract class
      auto
      do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void override
      {
        // this dispatches to the dynamic class implementation
        // ie. the class monmer will point to or reference to
        do_apply_displacement(displacement);
      }
    
    public:
      auto
      apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void
      {
        // calls the monomer class do_apply_displacement
        // which then dispatches to the implementation
        do_apply_displacement(displacement);
      }
    };
    
    // to get our implementation functionality only the virtual or overriden
    // function need to be implemented but we can have several functions as pleases
    // us
    class monomer_impl : public monomer
    {
      auto
      do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void override
      {
        std::cout << "monomer called do_apply_displacement of monomer_impl \n";
      }
    };
    
    class monomer_type_a : public monomer
    {
      auto
      do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void override
      {
        std::cout << "monomer called do_apply_displacement of monomer_type_a \n";
      }
    };
    class monomer_type_a_impl_grid : public monomer_type_a
    {
      auto
      do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void override
      {
        std::cout << "monomer called do_apply_displacement of "
                     "monomer_type_a_impl_grid \n";
      }
    };

    class monomer_type_a_impl : public monomer_impl
    {
    auto
       do_apply_displacement(vector displacement) -> void override
     {
    std::cout
        << "monomer called do_apply_displacement of monomer_type_a_impl \n";
     }
   };

    
    // if we like this style . It simplifies the creation of the implementations 
    // and the execution of our need functions
    class monomer_abstraction
    {
      std::unique_ptr<monomer> implementation_;
    
    public:
      explicit monomer_abstraction(monomer *inmplementation)
          : implementation_{ inmplementation }
      {
      }
    
      auto
      apply_displacement(vector displacement)
      {
        implementation_->apply_displacement(displacement);
      }
    };
    
    auto
    main() -> int
    {
      // using stack allocated monomer_type_a_impl_grid
      monomer_type_a_impl_grid impl_grid;
      monomer &monomer_grid = impl_grid;
      monomer_grid.apply_displacement(vector{});
    
      // using heap allocated monomer_impl
      auto impl_ = std::make_unique<monomer_impl>();
      monomer &monomer = *impl_;
      /// using virtual dispach apply_displacement will call the
      /// do_apply_displacement of it dynamic type
      monomer.apply_displacement(vector{});
    
      // using monomer_abstraction as an abstraction to the implementations
      // of need functionalities
      auto abstraction
          = monomer_abstraction(std::make_unique<monomer_type_a_impl>().release());
      abstraction.apply_displacement(vector{});
    }
```

Definately DRY is the way to go